# Calculating speed up and efficiency of a parallel program

Tags: multithreading

Lets say the least time taken for a parallel program is 25 ms for 32 threads and it takes 400 ms for 1 thread, how can I find speed up and efficiency of the program?
speed up = 400 / 25 = 16
efficiency = speedup /no. of threads = 0.5 x 100 = 50 %

Technically, if we calculate efficiency for 1 thread it will result in 100 %
Even when I calculated the efficiency for other number of threads that took more time, their efficiency was higher than the "optimum" time which took 32 threads.

So are my calculations correct? and how can I tell which is the most efficient?

Comment: Define "efficiency of a program". One thread is almost always more efficient that parallel computing because that causes overhead. The 32 threads take 800ms overall which is double the 400ms of the single thread. 16 times as fast with 32 times the resources, half as efficient.

Comment: Thank you... if I get given a number of threads as well as their runtime, and get asked to calculate the program's efficiency...should I calculate the efficiency depending on the number of threads that took the least amount of time? and is the method I used above correct?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "efficiency of a / the program" I would say all the numbers you need or can get out of it are in my last comment.

Comment: Okay Thanks, Actually the numbers I've given are just a random example. Did you get the 800 ms for 32 threads depending on the efficiency I calculated?

Comment: 25ms * 32threads => 800ms